# Phonegap symbian start up development

Tags: javascript, cordova, symbian

I have a problem to start developing for Symbian, i have already fully working app for android, now i need to start it on Symbian.
I've downloaded all from http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_getting-started_symbian_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Symbian

i tried: 
but when i try to start my .wgz file on emulator it goes : "Enable to install"..

Can you tell me from what to start? or send me some guides or tutorials?